# How to break out of promise-then chain in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request, soa

I am working on SOA project where I am writing a node js utility to get my things done. The utility starts with login to server using a SOA call then call a series of SOA call where each SOA call depends on the result of the previous call.

I have used `promise-then` framework to achieve this. Below is my code:

```
const loginPromise = postRequest(req, headersObj, loginUrl, Constants.loginData);
const queryPromise = loginPromise.then(loginSuccess, loginFailure);
const searchPromise = queryPromise.then(handleSavedQuerySearchResponse, onFailure);
const createPromise = searchPromise.then(handleSearchSoaResponse, onFailure);
const updatePromise = createPromise.then(handleCreateObjectSoaResposne, onFailure);
const plantDataPromise = updatePromise.then(handleUpdateObjectSoaResponse, onFailure);

function postRequest(request: any, header: any, reqUrl: string, jsonData: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        request.post({
            headers: header,
            url: reqUrl,
            body: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        }, (err: any, resp: any, bodyParam: any) => {
            resolve({error: err, response: resp, body: bodyParam});
        });
    });
}
```

On successful execution of the one SOA the next SOA gets executed from the `callback` function. Everything works fine when there is no error scenario. But if the server is down or in any other failure scenario I want to get out of this `promise-then` chain.

Currently on any error the flow gets to *`onFailure`* method but after its execution it gives the control to next promise in the chain with `null` as input for that method.

I want to get out of the promise-then chain whenever any error is encountered and rest of the promise should not get executed. I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: What is the "promise-then" framework? Are you talking about native promises?

Comment: Also what request framework are you using? Many request frameworks support promises out of the box today so you do not have to wrap the request.post in a new promise.

Anyway, this looks like kind of an unorthodox way of chaining promises. I would restructure it so that you either use async/await so that you can more or less keep your current structure, but with a try/catch block to do error handling instead of the onFailure callback, or to use regular promise chaining with .then and .catch. If you chain them normally and add a .catch-block at the end, you should get the behaviour you want

Comment: @Metareven Yes, I am using the native promise of the nodejs and using the request library of the node package `request@2.81.0`.

Comment: It will be really helpful if you could restructure it using the async/await and let me know how to handle the error scenarios. It will be great if you can add the try/catch block in the current structure and help me in achieving the desired behaviour.

Comment: You already identified the problem: don't handle errors with `onFailure` after *each* step - handle it once in the end of the chain!

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I was trying to achieve this, but it looks I was doing it in a wrong way. I am looking  for some better approach to get my things done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has not been tested and should as such be though of more as pseudocode than an actual solution:

Try to either restructure your code more like this:

```
const request = require('request-promise-native')

postRequest(req, headersObj, loginUrl, Constants.loginData)
    .then(loginSuccess)
    .then(handleSavedQuerySearchResponse)
    .then(handleSearchSoaResponse)
    .then(handleCreateObjectSoaResposne)
    .then(handleUpdateObjectSoaResponse)
    .catch(console.error)

function postRequest(request: any, header: any, reqUrl: string, jsonData: any): Promise<any> {
    return request.post({
        headers: header,
        url: reqUrl,
        body: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    }, (err: any, resp: any, bodyParam: any) => {
            resolve({error: err, response: resp, body: bodyParam});
    });
}
```

Where the error handling is a part of the promise chain.

Or you can do pretty much  the same with async/await.

You could add your onFailure function here instead of just console.error if you want to do some actual error handling

Comment: *"or you can do pretty much the same with async/await"* is slightly misleading in the sense that the syntax is *very* different. You should consider updating your answer to include an example, considering these days async / await is almost always a more idiomatic way of writing async code. Although, having said that, this is probably a scenario where chaining promises would actually be more succinct (assuming each promise relies on the result of the previous).

Comment: So what I understood from your code snippet is that any error occurring in of the promise will get caught in the catch block and in the catch block I can handle the respective error. Once the error is handled the next promise will not get invoked. Please correct me if I have wrong.

Comment: @Akash_Kumar Yes you assume correctly. Promises can be chained with the then, catch, finally methods. When a promise is rejected it will bubble down the promise chain until it hits a catch or is unhandled (which will give you a warning, might be upgraded into an exception in later versions of node). If you want to continue the chain after handling an error, all you have to do is to attach a .then after the .catch and continue chaining as normal. 

I will see if I can manage to squeeze out an updated answer with async/await, but I do not have the time to do that right now

Comment: @Metareven Thanks for support. I will try this and then will update the analysis.

Comment: According to original code, it likely should be `.catch(onFailure)`.